# How does Typescript inferred object literal type widening work?

Tags: typescript

I've read about how typescript widens [inferred types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) but am still unsure of what's going on [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20Def%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'T'%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%205%2C%20data%3A%20%7Br%3A%20'm'%7D%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20route%3CS%20extends%20keyof%20Def%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(route%3A%20S%2C%20handler%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CDef%5BS%5D%3E)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aroute('T'%2C%20async%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20status%3A%205%2C%20data%3A%20%7Br%3A%20'm'%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A):

```
type Def = {
  'T': { status: 5, data: {r: 'm'}},
}

function route<S extends keyof Def>
   (route: S, handler: () => Promise<Def[S]>) { }

route('T', async function () {
   return { status: 5, data: {r: 'm'} };
});
```

This works fine in the Typescript playground but shouldn't an error be raised because Typescript infers the type of the second argument to `route()` to be `() => {status: number, data: {r: string}}`?

I ask because I'm having an issue with [this code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ApiDefBase%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bpath%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AppApiDef%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Fsample'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GET%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%3A%20%7B%20count%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Ftest'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20POST%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Router%3CApiDef%20extends%20ApiDefBase%20%3D%20AppApiDef%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CPath%20extends%20keyof%20ApiDef%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20Path%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20input%3A%20ApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'params'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20req%3A%20Request%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res%3A%20Response%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'response'%5D%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Router().get('%2Fapi%2Fsample'%2C%20async%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%2C%20data%3A%20%7B%20message%3A%20'Success'%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A). The function passed into `Router::get` is inferred as `() => {status: number}` instead of `() => {status: 200}`. Oddly enough, no error is raised when I remove the `POST` route ([shown here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ApiDefBase%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bpath%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AppApiDef%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Fsample'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GET%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%3A%20%7B%20count%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Ftest'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GET%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Router%3CApiDef%20extends%20ApiDefBase%20%3D%20AppApiDef%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CPath%20extends%20keyof%20ApiDef%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20Path%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20input%3A%20ApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'params'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20req%3A%20Request%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res%3A%20Response%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'response'%5D%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Router().get('%2Fapi%2Fsample'%2C%20async%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%2C%20data%3A%20%7B%20message%3A%20'Success'%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)).

Answer (score 1):

This simple example does work as expected and literal type widening does not happen here - function `route()` is generic, and `S` is inferred first, because you are calling it without specifying its generic type parameter `S`:

```
route('T', async function () {
   return { status: 5, data: {r: 'm'} };
});
```

so, first of all,  the compiler has to infer `S` from the types of actual arguments passed.

By looking at the first argument, literal `'T'`,  it determines `S` to be literal type `'T'`.

So immediately, the return type of second argument, `() => Promise<Def[S]>` becomes fixed to the object literal type defined as `Def['T']`. Then the compiler does not need to infer the return type for async function, it just checks that it conforms to the `Def['T']` (which is does).

Why this does not work [in this, more complex code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ApiDefBase%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bpath%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AppApiDef%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Fsample'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GET%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%3A%20%7B%20count%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20'%2Fapi%2Ftest'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20POST%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20response%3A%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Router%3CApiDef%20extends%20ApiDefBase%20%3D%20AppApiDef%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CPath%20extends%20keyof%20ApiDef%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20Path%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler%3A%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20input%3A%20ApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'params'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20req%3A%20Request%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res%3A%20Response%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CApiDef%5BPath%5D%5B'GET'%5D%5B'response'%5D%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Router().get('%2Fapi%2Fsample'%2C%20async%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20status%3A%20200%2C%20data%3A%20%7B%20message%3A%20'Success'%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A) I don't know, but I suspect that the index signature in `ApiDefBase` prevents the effect of type inference on `Path` -  if you add similar index signature to the simple example you will start getting the same error:

```
type DefBase = { [p in string]: {}}

interface Def extends DefBase {
  'T': { status: 5, data: {r: 'm'}},
}

function route<S extends keyof Def>
   (route: S, handler: () => Promise<Def[S]>) { }

route('T', async function () {
   return { status: 5, data: {r: 'm'} };
});

Argument of type '() => Promise<{ status: number; data: { r: string; }; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Promise<{ status: 5; data: { r: "m"; }; }>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ status: number; data: { r: string; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ status: 5; data: { r: "m"; }; }>'.
    Type '{ status: number; data: { r: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ status: 5; data: { r: "m"; }; }'.
      Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type '5'.
```

Now, why does adding index signature have this effect on type inference - I have no idea.